# Fetch records for last month through nifi

Tags: list, date, apache-nifi

I have two files in my server like '**abcd.2023-04**' and '**efgh.2023-05**' the format is (yyyy-mm). I want to list all the files in the server and fetch the last month file. As the current month is **05** I want to fetch the file with **04** month. This should be a recurring process, like for **06** month I need to get the file of **05** month and so on. How can I achieve this through nifi